# Why isn't my range regex syntax working?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to say match a string that contains between 3 and 4 consecutive numbers.  But my braces syntax isn't working

```
2.4.0 :034 > data = "1234"
 => "1234"
2.4.0 :035 > data =~ /\d{3, 4}/
 => nil
```

What's the ocrrect way to say this?

Comment: Your example works just fine for me??  Admittedly mine returns 0 which is correct as my string was found at that position which is what your test returns.  You can use the anchors as shown, but if you have a five digit number which does contain a number with 3-4 numbers in it, it will not show with the anchors

Comment: Well, I read the question as "match *full* string that contains between 3 and 4 consecutive numbers". I edited my answer to be more precise.

Comment: Using bos/eos anchors is a crutch used by the inexperienced ..

Comment: @grail this is actually interpreted as match a number (`\d`) followed by the literal `{3, 4}` where the space is an implicit literal similar to `{3,\s4}` is an explicit literal. so it would match a string like `12{3, 4}` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/vsm6aCw1x8)

Comment: This [website](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2EszJx1fBWt1I4rq) is very helpful with regexen.

Comment: @EricDuminil - Personally, I don't use bos/eos anchors when searching for substrings. I'm guessing you use these anchors  all the time because you use open ended quantifiers without knowing how to use other boundary's. Am I right dude?

Comment: @sln. The opposite of "never" isn't "all the time", it's "sometimes". I know how to use `\b` or lookarounds, thank you very much, no need for trolling or calling me dude. I sometimes use bos/eos anchors to check that a string has the correct format, and not `"the_correct_format\nand_some_malicious_data"`.

Comment: @EricDuminil - To each his own bro. Like I said it's used as a crutch for the inexperienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space inside the [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
data =~ /\d{3,4}/
```

If you want to match the *entire* string consisting of just 3 to 4 digits, use

```
data =~ /\A\d{3,4}\z/
```

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\d{3,4}` - 3 to 4 digits
- `\z` - end of string.

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/CYsYgiUoG4).

Comment: Is this the answer? This doesn't explain why the op regex didn't match.

Comment: Wow @sln flaming out a bit here seems this part **"Remove the space inside the limiting quantifier:"** kind of covers the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is interpreted as

```
 \d{3,[ ]4}
```

That's why it doesn't work.

Remove the space

Your regex is trying to match this

```
 \d       # digit
 {        # literal
 3        # literal
 ,        # literal
 [ ]      # class
 4        # literal
 }        # literal
```

Comment: as @EricDuminil pointed out white space ignorance does not make a literal into a limiting qualifier. it just means this would match `12{3,4}` instead

Comment: `"1234" =~ /(?x:\d{3, 4})/ # => ?`

Comment: @sln Yes you are correct it will not ignore that whitespace and change the context it will ignore the whitespace while retaining the context of match number and literal.  this is not ruby specific [Example](https://regex101.com/r/XM9ybu/1) PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) do not work this way nor do python regex. Can you show me a language that does?

Comment: Perl and at least boost::regex. I think pcre but I don't trust online testers.

Comment: Btw, my answer was `Your regex is interpreted as \d{3,[ ]4}`. If you think that's wrong, show me.

Comment: for your edification I was able to confirm that Java will use the `x` flag as you stated however I cannot confirm that perl agrees with your statement (version tested 5.24.1)--it does however warn you about an unescaped left brace which is nice

Comment: @engineersmnky - The unescaped left brace warning (use strict; use warnings;) comes and goes with different versions depending what side of the bed this guy woke up on.  Perl v5.20 © Larry Wall: use re 'debug'; `/\d * ? /x` => `\d*?` ..|.. `/\d {1,2} /x` => `\d{1,2}` ..|.. `/\d{1, 2}/x` = > `1: POSIXD[\d] (2) 2: EXACT <{1,2}> (5) 5: END (0)` Little bit of an irony there don't you think.. When I parse regular expressions given x-mode scope, _any_ whitespace in the range quantifier is ok. And, almost everywhere else, except when it is the begin of a parenthesis  construct token (any/all).

Comment: Here we go on Perl: `And note that /x doesn't affect space interpretation within a single multi-character construct. For example in \x{...} , regardless of the /x modifier, there can be no spaces. Same for a quantifier such as {3} or {5,} . Similarly, (?:...) can't have a space between the "{" , "?" , and ":"` - Little special rules for little special folks. And I mean special. If you forget to add a hex/octal value/digit in  `\x`, `\o`, well those little special folks fill it in for you. Wait, where did that come from.. Doc errors in this https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Fwiw - `\p{Pattern_White_Space=Yes}` = `[\x{9}-\x{D}\x{20}\x{85}\x{200E}-\x{200F}\x{2028}-\x{2029}]`